# KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ ... dtype='int64', length=802)] are in the [columns]

Tags: python, pandas, keras, neural-network

How to deal with this index problem when using keras? Looking at my shape everything looks normal:

```
X = DF.iloc[:, 0:10]
Y = DF.iloc[:, 10:15]

X.shape, Y.shape

((1003, 10), (1003, 5))
```

**X e Y:**

[image]

[image]

**Training:**

```
for train, test in kfold.split(X,Y):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10,
                kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),
                kernel_initializer=VarianceScaling(), 
                activation='sigmoid',
                name='hidden-input'))
    model.add(Dense(5, 
                kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001),
                kernel_initializer=VarianceScaling(),                 
                activation='sigmoid',
                name='output'))
    
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
    
    model.fit(X[train], Y[train], epochs=50, batch_size=5, verbose = 0,
              validation_data=(X[test], Y[test]))

    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], Y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)
```

**Output:**

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 201,  202,  203,  204,  205,  206,  207,  208,  209,  210,\n            ...\n             993,  994,  995,  996,  997,  998,  999, 1000, 1001, 1002],\n           dtype='int64', length=802)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Try `X.loc[train]` or `X.iloc[train]` instead.

Comment: Output: `ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=        mean_1 `

Comment: `model.fit(X.loc[train], Y.loc[train]...`

Comment: `validation_data=(X.iloc[test], Y.loc[test]))`

Comment: `scores = model.evaluate(X.loc[test], Y.loc[test], verbose=0)`

Comment: @QuangHoang thIs resolved: `X.iloc[train].values`, is it correct to use this?

Comment: Yes, that passes a copy of the data as a numpy array to the model. That should work just fine.